# Cadastro personalizado de usuários no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Preciso cadastrar usuários no wordpress, e cadastrar informações desse usuário em uma outra tabela do banco de dados

```
global $wpdb;

if( count($_POST) > 0) {

$userdata = array(
    'user_login'  =>  $_POST['nome'],
    'user_url'    =>  'http://example.com',
    'user_pass'   =>  NULL, // When creating an user, `user_pass` is expected.
    'role' => 'editor'
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );

    $cadastro = $wpdb->insert( 'usuarios',
                                array(
                                        'idusuarios' => $user_id,
                                        'nome' => $_POST['nome'],
                                        'idade' => $_POST['idade'],
                                        'cidade' => $_POST['cidade']
                                )
                            );
    if( $cadastro > 0 ) {
        echo "Cadastrado com sucesso!";
    } else {
        echo"Erro! não foi possível cadastrar";
    }
}
```

Mas aparece esse erro:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string,
>   object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rondoloc\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line
>   1127

Erros no debug.log :

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: nome in C:\xampp\htdocs\rondoloc\wp-content\themes\rondoloc\page-cadastro.php on line 13
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: nome in C:\xampp\htdocs\rondoloc\wp-content\themes\rondoloc\page-cadastro.php on line 24
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: idade in C:\xampp\htdocs\rondoloc\wp-content\themes\rondoloc\page-cadastro.php on line 25
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: cidade in C:\xampp\htdocs\rondoloc\wp-content\themes\rondoloc\page-cadastro.php on line 26
>
> Erro de banco de dados do WordPress 
>   Column 'nome' cannot be null para a consulta INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`idusuarios`, `nome`, `idade`, `cidade`) VALUES ('', NULL, NULL, NULL)
>
> feita por require('C:\xampp\htdocs\rondoloc\wp-blog-header.php'),
>
> require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\rondoloc\wp-includes\template-loader.php'),
>
> include('C:\xampp\htdocs\rondoloc\wp-content\themes\rondoloc\page-cadastro.php')

Comment: Experimente fazer um debug e anexar o log a pergunta. 1) Abra o seu `wp-config.php` 2)  Adicionar estas três linhas lá: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`
`define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);`
`define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);` 3) Abra a página problemática e depois copie e cole o conteúdo de `wp-content/debug.log` na pergunta usando a `formatação`. [Referencia](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ali no user_pass tá null...e tá dizendo no comentário "Quando um usuário for criado, user_pass é esperado... Uma string...E o Null tá retornando em forma de objeto...
Talvez um $_POST['nomeDoCampoSenha'],
resolva...

Comment: obrigado, fiz a alteração que me indicou e inseriu no banco de dados, mas o primeiro erro continua aparecendo

Comment: Seguinte :"mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rondoloc\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1127" Isso significa : que a função "mysqli...string()" espera o parâmetro 2 pra ser uma string, objeto dado....linha 1127... então a função espera uma string e tá recebendo um objeto...PQ objeto? --->>>Erro de banco de dados do WordPress Column 'nome' cannot be null para a consulta INSERT INTO usuarios (idusuarios, nome, idade, cidade) VALUES ('', NULL, NULL, NULL) esse parâmetro NULL está sendo interpretado como objeto e ele precisa ser uma string.

Comment: Entendi, valeu cara, como coloquei uma condição no começo do bloco, ele não entra no bloco, e só entra após eu passar as strings via POST, e não apresenta o erro, assim fazendo o insert no banco de dados

Comment: Quando quiser validar a resposta, caso ela tenha sido útil, finaliza ai ao lado